# How to add Sales Tax Item to QuickBooks Desktop?

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am using QB  desktop edition. I am creating all Items like Inventory/Service/OtherCharge/Payment in QB through IDS,but I am not able to add -'Sales Tax Item' throgh my .net code,because

Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.ItemTypeEnum - Having only  Assembly/FixedAsset/Group/Inventory/Service/OtherCharge/Payment.Product/SubTotal. and not Sales Tax Item.

Is there any other way to create  Sales Tax Item ?

Please help.

Regards,

Reshma D.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `SalesTax` object instead.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Add xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" RequestId="26d2185e14e24563afe3ea451f70440b" xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
   <ExternalRealmId>132875294</ExternalRealmId>
   <Object xsi:type="SalesTax">
     <Name>All ST</Name>
     <Desc>County supplemental tax</Desc>
     <TaxRate>10</TaxRate>
     <VendorName>Franchise Tax Board</VendorName>
   </Object>
</Add>
```

Documentation is [here](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0600_Object_Reference/SalesTax).